# Rails form select "selected" parameter not working for email options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form, ransack

I have a series of select boxes in a search form for which I need to retain the selected options when the form is submitted and the results loaded.  I'm using a templated form select that is properly selecting 3 out of the 4 inputs after form submission (via POST).  The input for selecting emails is not working properly -- curiously, it works only for some of the options.

Since the select boxes are templated, I figure it must be related to the content somehow. Or I am just overlooking something really simple...

Random or not-so-random fact:  there are currently four email addresses that populate the select options.  Two do not reload as selected when chosen and submitted, and they "happen" to be emails I didn't just make up and I have stored logins for them in Firefox 56.  But, I tried it on Chrome and the same two emails don't pre-select there either.  Only one of them is a saved login in Chrome.

I'm stumped.

I am on Rails 5.1.4, using Ransack 1.8.3 and Simpleform 3.5.0.  The select boxes are prettied up using Selectize 0.12.4.

**Controller**

```
class Admin::StoriesController < ApplicationController

layout "admin"
before_action :set_search_variables

def index
    @stories = @q.result.page params[:page]
end

def search
    index
    render :index
end

...

private

def story_params
    allowed = [
        :name,
        :story,
        :email,
        :organization,
        :image,
        :published,
        :user_profession,
        :reviewed,
        :image_delete
    ]
    params.require(:story).permit(allowed)
end

def set_search_variables
    @q = Story.order(created_at: :desc).ransack(params[:q])
    @options = Story.select([:name, :organization, :email, :user_profession])
end
...
```

end

**Search Form**

```
<%= search_form_for [:admin, @q], url: search_admin_stories_path, html: { method: :post }, class: "pt-4 mod-search-form" do |f| %>

...

<%= render partial: 'admin/_forms/select', locals: { label: "Name", search_param: :name_eq, attribute: :name, f: f } %>

<%= render partial: 'admin/_forms/select', locals: { label: "Email", search_param: :email_eq, attribute: :email, f: f } %>

<%= render partial: 'admin/_forms/select', locals: { label: "Organization", search_param: :organization_eq, attribute: :organization, f: f } %>

<%= render partial: 'admin/_forms/select', locals: { label: "Profession", search_param: :user_profession_eq, attribute: :user_profession, f: f } %>

...

<%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-block my-4 w-75 mx-auto" %>
<%= f.button "Reset", type: :button, id: :search_reset, class: "btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary w-50 mx-auto mb-4 d-block" %>
```

**Select partial**

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label search_param, label %>
<%= f.select search_param,
    options_from_collection_for_select(@options.order(attribute),
    attribute,
    attribute,
    request.method.eql?("POST") ? params[:q][search_param] : ""),
    {include_blank: "Any"},
    "data-placeholder": "Any",
    class: "form-control"
%>
</div>
```

**and the Selectize js**

```
$('select').selectize({
    selectOnTab: true,
    allowEmptyOption: true
});
```

Comment: Do you have your `:search_param` set as `attr_accessor` on your model?

Comment: I don't understand why that would be necessary, or why it would work for all the others when none of them are marked w/ attr_accessor; however, I tried it anyway -- no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this one out.  The problem was that the "selected" parameter for *options_from_collection_for_select* was finding more than one option with the same value.  As you can see in my example above, I was using the attribute name as both the *value* and the *text* methods.

The select boxes loaded the correct "selected" option after submit for any option that only occurred once in the db.  However, for example, an email, e.g. admin@example.com, was used for more than one Story, then the selected option became ambiguous, and it just selected nothing.

My solution is to create the options with a different, more generic method (*options_for_select*), making sure the array of options is **unique**:

**New Select Partial**

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label search_param, label %>
<%= f.select search_param,
    options_for_select(prepare_select_options_for(@options, attribute),
    request.method.eql?("POST") ? [params[:q][search_param]] : ""),
    {include_blank: "Any"},
    "data-placeholder": "Any",
    class: "form-control"
%>
</div>
```

**Helper method**

```
def prepare_select_options_for(collection, attr)
    attr = attr.to_sym
    collection.
        order(attr).
        map(&attr).
        reject(&:blank?).
        uniq
end
```

Works like a charm now!